# Ignore part of function during tests

Tags: rust

I have an application that calls a function that, at the end, has a piece of logic that takes a while to run. I already test this logic independently since it is it's own function but it currently makes my tests take much longer than I would like them to.

Is there a way I can make the long running function run during normal usage but not when I'm testing the `hello_world` function?

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=65725b5f9086142d7594550ea8bf3d64)

```rust
fn main() {
    hello_world();
}

fn hello_world() {
    println!("Hello, world!");

    // Can I ignore this when testing?
    long_running_function();
}

fn long_running_function() {
    for i in 1..100000 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

#[test]
fn hello_world_test() {
    hello_world();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `#[cfg(not(test))]`:

```rs
#[cfg(not(test))]
long_running_function();
```

Or the macro equivalent:

```rs
if !cfg!(test) {
    long_running_function();
}
```

A common approach in unit-testing is to mock external functions, it is possible to provide two separate implementations of `long_running_function` depending if it is compiled for test or target.

```rs
#[cfg(not(test))]
fn long_running_function() {
    for i in 1..100000 {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn long_running_function() {
    // not so long code
}
```

Else you can always pass a boolean to `hello_world()` and make a condition based on this boolean.

Comment: put `#[cfg(not(test))]` around the definition of `longfunction` and write an alternative mock for testing. I think that is cleaner than have a macro around the call.

Comment: @Simson good point! I'll add it to the answer